# Instantiating ServiceController takes sometimes too much time

Tags: c#, servicecontroller, remote-registry

i am creating an instance of ServiceController using a remote/local machine name
and the name of the service. When I type sth. like stackoverflow.com as machine name the contructor blocks for a long time and returns an exception.

Example:

```
string MachineName = "stackoverflow.com"
ServiceController("RemoteRegistry", MachineName );
```

How can I set here a kind of timeout to cancel this process?

Answer (score 1):

This is subject to the standard TCP/IP connection time-outs.  The same ones you see when trying to visit a web site that's off line with your browser.  Yes, you can change them by editing the registry.  You can make them longer.  Not shorter.

Perhaps you can [ping it first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) if this often fails.